# How to keep a single row based on mathematical operations on few columns of a text file in using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file like this with say 5 columns:

```
col#1 col#2    col#3    col#4   col#5

1    14361   19759   A      ROMAN
1    14406   29370   B      ROMAN
2    33445   55667   D      GREEK
```

What I want to do is, perform subtraction like this `col#3` - `col#2` for identical values in column#5 (`col#5`) i.e;

```
1    14361   19759   A      ROMAN
1    14406   29370   B      ROMAN
```

subtraction of `col#3` - `col#2` for identical values of `col#5`

`19759` - `14361` gives `5398`

and `29370` - `14406` gives `14964`

and keep only that row where the result of subtraction is larger; final result will look something like this

```
col#1 col#2    col#3    col#4   col#5

1    14406   29370   B      ROMAN
2    33445   55667   D      GREEK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = []
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = line.split()
        d.append(int(d[2]) - int(d[1]))
        data += [d]            
out = []
for i in set([o[4] for o in data]):
    for j in set([o[0] for o in data if o[4] == i]):
        out += [max([a for a in data if a[4] == i and a[0] == j], key=lambda x: x[5])]

with open('b.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in out:
        f.write('{} {} {} {} {}\n'.format(*line[:-1]))

In [31]: cat b.txt
2 33445 55667 D GREEK
2 14260 19760 C ROMAN
1 14406 29370 B ROMAN
```

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi mamun

that does works as expected , however , I see a different scenario for some rows as described below (notice different values of col#1 for identical values
of col#5):

```
col#1 col#2    col#3    col#4   col#5

1    14361   19759   A      ROMAN
1    14406   29370   B      ROMAN
2    14261   19758   C      ROMAN 
2    14260   19760   C      ROMAN 
2    33445   55667   D      GREEK
```
It should give output like

```
col#1 col#2    col#3    col#4   col#5

1    14406   29370   B      ROMAN
2    14260   19760   C      ROMAN
2    33445   55667   D      GREEK
```

Comment: in other words, from these 2 enteries
```
1    14361   19759   A      ROMAN
1    14406   29370   B      ROMAN
```
it should give
```
1    14361   19759   A      ROMAN
```
and from these 2 enteries
```
2    14261   19758   C      ROMAN 
2    14260   19760   C      ROMAN
```
it should give
```
2    14260   19760   C      ROMAN
```